# How to inherit all typedefs from one base class under multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have two base class with a bunch of typedefs:

```
struct X {
  typedef int type1;
  typedef float type2;
  // A bunch of other typedefs.
};

struct Y {
  typedef long type1;
  typedef char type3;
  // Some other typedefs.
};

struct Z : public X, public Y {
};
```

How do I specify I want to let Z inherit all typedefs from X, without manually resolving conflicts for each type?  I mean O(1) code to achieve this instead of O(n), where n is the number of conflict types.  Also in the case of meta programing, one wouldn't know the exact typedefs in X and Y, so manual resolving conflict is not possible.

Under the case of single inheritance, it will automatically use the base class's typedef so I don't need to manually specify them.

Comment: Why not put all the types you need in a header file?

Answer (score 4):

Uhm, it works just fine. You only need to resolve the collisions.

```
struct X
{
    typedef int type1;
    typedef int type2;
};

struct Y
{
    typedef double type1;
};

struct Z : public X, public Y 
{
    type2 z1;
    typedef X::type1 type1;
    type1 z2;
};

int main()
{
    Z z;
    Z::type2 x;
    Z::type1 y;
}
```

Comment: Your answer works but requires manual work to resolve conflicts.  I updated my question to make it clear what I am looking for.  Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: @icando That can't be done. You need to manually resolve conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Use `private` or `protected` inheritance instead of `public` inheritance, and then use `using` statement to declare the items you want to use in `Z`, eg:

```
struct Z : protected X, protected Y
{ 
    using X::type1;
    using X::type2;
    // ...
};
```